# How to create product combination from two, three or more products

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I am trying to make someting like in the following link, using Magento:

http://www.sterlingsilverjewelry.tv/genuine-pearl-925-sterling-silver-dangle-earrings-sjhe0045pearl-ss.html

You can see that product main images and all other detsails change.

Now I tried configuring a bundled product with combination of two or more simple products, but this will create too many products.

Suppose I cofigure the following:

1: 3 products of stones
2: 2 products of ring base
3: Than the total number of products that I will have to create will be 3(stones) + 2(stone base) +6(3*2 bundled product with all possible combinations) = 11 products
For more options, this will be to complicated to manage.

How can we use Magento to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for configurable product.

An example for bundle product would be a Set of 1x Earrings + 1x Ring, which is not the case.